# When hover on province map doesn't show graph in tooltip

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, plotly, topojson

I am making a map using d3js and when I hover on a province it should display a pie chart of its cities made using plotly. But it is not displaying it.

Now I have added a tooltip which display province name properly but when I pass another div with id ChartDiv it doesn't display the graph. Infact when I hover the div inside the tooltip div disappears.

```
<style>
#tooltip, #ChartDiv{
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px;
  background: #d22424;
  border: 0px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
</style>
<body>
   <div id = 'tooltip' style="display: none">
       <div id="ChartDiv"></div>
   </div>
<script>
//When mouseover on province
function mouseover(d){
          tooltip.transition()
          .duration(200);
            tooltip.html(map_chart(mapData,prov_name))
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 50) + "px")
            .style("opacity", 1)
            .style('display','block');
        }
//When mouseout on province
        function mouseout(){
          tooltip.transition()
            .duration(500)
            .style("opacity", 0);
        }

//Plotly Graph
            var data = [{
                values: ValArr,
                labels: LabelArr,
                sort: false,
                type: 'pie'
              }];
             Plotly.newPlot('ChartDiv', data, {}, {showSendToCloud:false})
</script>
</body>
```

I expect that the graph is shown over the province.but when I try above method it just removes the div ChartDiv so I get this error No Element with id Chart Div Found.

Here is the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/inshalsaleem/vdag3qLu/2/

Please help me regarding this problem.

Comment: Tip: You can get better response on your issue if you create a fiddle for this.

Comment: You are not actually returning anything from the `map_chart` function. That is the first thing. So what is happening is the `div` with the id of *tooltip* is having it's `html` set to undefined. So you need to return something from the `map_chart` function. Secondly, it looks like `Plotly.newPlot()` returns a `Promise`, so you'll need to use logic such as `map_chart(province_name).then(createdHtml => { restOfMouseoverLogic(createdHtml); });`